# Angular Openapi-generator-cli with useSingleRequestParameter don't use snake_case

Tags: angular, openapi, camelcasing, openapi-generator-cli, snakecase

i'm using this cli to generate my services in angular

```
openapi-generator-cli generate -i ./openapi.yaml -g typescript-angular -o src/app/core/api/v1 --additional-properties=useSingleRequestParameter=true,modelPropertyNaming=snake_case
```

i have a model called `Item` autogenerated my this cli with some fields like `created_on`

```
export interface Item { 
    readonly id: number;
    readonly collection: number;
    active?: boolean;
    readonly created_on: string;
    readonly updated_on: string;
    name: string;
    relase_date?: string | null;
}
```

almost all works fine except for generated RequestParams like
for `ItemsCreateRequestParams` `ItemsPartialUpdateRequestParams`

```
export interface ItemsCreateRequestParams {
    name: string;
    active?: boolean;
    description?: string;
    relaseDate?: string | null;
}
```

as you can see relaseDate generated is in camelCase instead of snake_case,

i tried adding `modelPropertyNaming=snake_case` but still generates RequestParams with wrong namig

did you know how fix it?